# How can I search voicemail transcripts?

Tags: iphone, search, visual-voicemail

I want to find a particular voicemail message on my phone by searching the automatically generated transcripts. How can I do that? I've got an iPhone SE (2020 version) running iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the built in Voicemail functionality. You could submit feedback to Apple to suggest they add such a feature to a future iOS update at [feedbackassistant.apple.com](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).